# how to get specific value from php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried multiple solutions but none seems to work for me Basically I am pulling facebook page likes and it puts them in an array and then i want to display a specific value from that array but i am not able to do that no matter what, below is my code:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/22992739859?fields=name,fan_count&access_token=my access token';

$t = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $t, $matches);

print_r($matches [0]);

?>
```

and the output is

```
Array ( [0] => 158060 [1] => 22992739859 )
```

I just want to get rid of the all the text except the value after [0]

is there anyway i can do that? I tried several solutions but none of them seemed to work for me.

Thanks

Comment: use `echo $matches [0]` instead of `print_r($matches [0]);`

Comment: it seems to be a multidimensional array so in fact `echo $matches[0][0]` may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$matches[0] fetches the 0th index of the $matches array which also happens to be an array. You can just gran the 0th index of that as well.

```
$result = $matches[0][0];
print_r($result);
```

Comment: genius thanks a lot this one worked like a charm. How did you determine that its a multi dimensional array?